# Linux : Can a directory rename be partially executed due to a power/transient mechanical failure in Server/Disk?

Tags: c++, linux

C/C++ rename function can be used to rename a directory.
Assume below situation (for Linux)
Directory X has files A, B and C.
X is renamed to Y (using C/C++ rename function). While the operation is in progress Server/Disk's power goes out. Then it is restarted.
Now is there a possibility of few files being in a directory X while others in Y.
e.g.
X : B
Y : A, C

Comment: _"C/C++ rename function"_ There's no such function in the C or C++ standard. Are you referring to the linux OS API?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There is `std::filesystem::rename`.

Comment: `Can a directory rename be partially executed..` Yes it can. And it happened, it was normal. Currently filesystems try to handle such cases. To get more specific answer, you need to specify the filesystem type. For advanced filesystems "rename" should be a "atomic" (fast, non-blocking) operation - the crucial part is changing like a single byte on the underlying block device. `Server/Disk?` - you have to specify if the filesystem and underlying block device are mounted via some (netowrk?) sharing mechanism, or mounted locally. As the question is now, it is (way) too broad. It may, depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename is only changing a name. The "id" of the file, and in linux a directory is a file which contains the "links" to other files and directories, stays the same!

As a file system is always directly relying to the physical block storage on any kind of hardware, always the complete block where the label is stored, must be rewritten and linked in the file system structure.

If a power fail happens in between, the "directory file" can be corrupted. This means, that more than the single renaming operations is involved!

BUT:
Modern file systems have many options to detect and repair such situations. E.G. ext4 has a journal in background. If any access may be interrupted, the journal has the information that these operation has started but not completed. By mounting such a partition/fs, the repair takes place automatically. If this is not possible, a fschk can do that job.

The situation, that only "some files" have been moved, is definitely never possible, because renaming a directory is not creating a new directory and moving the file names/links to the node id into the new directory, it is only a new name for an existing directory.

As a user: Simply use modern file systems and mostly all power down failures can be recovered by restart. You may find your filesystem in the "old" or the "new" version, but not in between.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on implementation but for all file systems I know renaming is just replacing a label. So renaming of a directory doesn't differ from file rename operation.
And when you rename a file and turn off power you never end up with two files X and Y each having half of the file content.